# Initializing Objective-C class ivar that is a C array

Tags: objective-c, c, arrays

I have an ivar in my Obj-C class that's a C array (I'm not interested in making it an Obj-C property). Simple enough. Now in my class's init method I'd like to seed this array with some values using the C array shorthand init as seen in my .m below. But I'm fairly positive this is creating a local variable by the same name and not initializing my instance variable. I can't put my array init in the interface and I cannot declare an ivar in an implementation. Am I just stuck doing some sort of deep copy over or do I have another option?

In GameViewController.h

```
#define kMapWidth 10
#define kMapHeight 10

@interface GameViewController : UIViewController
{
    unsigned short map[kMapWidth * kMapHeight];
}

@end
```

In GameViewController.m

```
- (id)init
{
    if ((self = [super init]))
    {
        unsigned short map[kMapWidth * kMapHeight] = { 
            1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
            1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
            1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
            1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
            1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
            1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
            1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
            1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
            1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
            1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
        };
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right. What you are doing is initializing a local variable, shadowing the instance variable. You can initialize a local array and `memcpy` it to the instance variable:

```
static const unsigned short localInit[] = { 
        1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
        1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
        1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
        1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
        1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
        1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
        1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
        1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
        1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
        1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
};

memcpy(map, localInit, sizeof(localInit));
```